# Understanding mosfet drive voltage

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I am planning to work with this [N-mosfet - SiSA72DN](http://www.vishay.com/docs/75680/sisa72dn.pdf)

Max ratings:

[image: max ratings]

Specs:

[image: specs]

Does this mean: I need to apply a voltage > 2.4 V on the gate to turn it on fully and the applied voltage must be < 20 V?

Application - Switching 5 V and 24 V loads.

Confirmation: Will the following schematic work for switching both 5V and 24V? Is there any improvement I can make to this circuit?

Note - 3.3 V will be provided by a GPIO.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxJvsD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes that should work, in case there's really a lamp, don't forget the free wheeling diode.

Comment: Load is LED strip. I will put a freewheel diode. What position is preferred? - Parallel to load or parallel to diode (D,S)? Do I even need a freewheel diode in case of LED strip?

Comment: I'd say diodes are not inductive loads and therefore don't require a freewheeling diode...

Comment: @Humpawumpa In your first comment you caused confusion by stating that the diode should be there when using a lamp.

Comment: It is not *guaranteed* to work; Rds(on) is stated at a *minimum* Vgs of 4.5V so the actual on state drain source resistance will be somewhat higher. The *typical* performance curve shows that at about 12 mOhm for around 3.3V drive, but that is informative and not binding (only the parameter tables are guaranteed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed \$V_{GS}\$ should not exceed the maximum rating of 20 V.

That 2.4 V is the **maximum** threshold voltage, so some devices may have a threshold voltage of 2.4 V. If you'd then apply a \$V_{GS}\$ = 2.5 V the "overdrive" would be only 2.5 V - 2.4 V = 0.1 V which isn't a lot. The MOSFET will probably not turn on fully.

What I usually do is apply a \$V_{GS}\$ that is the same or higher than the \$V_{GS}\$ that the manufacturer uses to specify \$R_{DS,on}\$. Here \$R_{DS,on}\$ is specified at \$V_{GS}\$ = 4.5 V and 10 V. Unless you really need the extra low \$R_{DS,on}\$ I would use at a \$V_{GS}\$ of **at least 4.5 V.**

Regarding the freewheel (or flyback) diode: you only need it for an **inductive** load, so relay coils, motors etc. For a lightbulb or LED strip the diode is not needed.

Comment: Since my MCU is 3.3 V based, I will use a voltage level shifter to translate my 3.3V logic to 5V. I think that should solve the problem.

Comment: If you're designing for a product that will sell in large numbers: yes I would translate to 5 V **or** use a MOSFET with a **guaranteed** \$R_{DS,on}\$ at \$V_{GS}\$= 3.3 V. If this is just for a hobby project, or only a small number of boards, I'd apply 3.3 V to the gate, measure what voltage drop I get. Decide if that is low enough and if it is, just use 3.3 V.

Comment: It's going to be a commercial product and I don't want to compromise on the quality. Thanks for your quick response, Bimp :)

Answer (score 2):

Notice the behavior at Vt(max of 2.4v) only guarantees 250uA thru the drain.

You need Vgate to be much greater than 2.4 volts.

Are there curves?

The 3rd line (spec) up from bottom, in the 2nd table, shows 30amps AT 25 degree Centigrade CASE TEMPERATURE with 10 volts on the gate.

The 2nd line (spec) up makes promises about 4.5 volts behavior.

Thus 3.3 volts on gate is risky for a commercial product with warrantee requirements.

Comment: Thanks analog. Now I understand this stuff better. I am planning to drive it with 5 V in order to stay safe.